# finite and infinite fields with prime characteristics

Tags: field-theory

Could any one give me two examples of finite and infinite fields, differ form Z/2Z, with char(F)=2 ? Also, I need some good books with examples to understand that kind of field.

Comment: In asking for a book recommendation it is almost essential that you explain your background and current understanding of a topic.  A sentence or two is all that is needed to help your Readers respond in a useful way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finite: $F_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)$ yields the field of four elements, which has characteristic $2$.

Infinite: Take $F_2(X)$, the field of quotients for the polynomial ring $F_2[x]$.

It depends on what you mean by "understand that kind of field" to give a book recommendation. When studying geometry through linear algebra and quadratic forms, one discovers that the characteristic 2 case is very exceptional, so it takes some time to understand. Mathoverflow [has a pretty good question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/91710) along these lines.

Any book covering finite fields would surely cover everything you want to know about the finite fields of characteristic $2$.

Comment: Thanks for helping .thanks a lot.